Can I call System.setProperty in Selenium Java then read it in the main app?
I need to set a flag in a java web app if it's running under a Selenium Java test.
The Selenium test code starts with:
 System.setProperty("testRunning", "true");

Then selenium launches the main web app which calls System.getProperty("testRunning") but the return value is null.
I'm using TestNG and tried calling System.setProperty in a custom listener class defined in testng.xml but this didn't help.
Maybe I need to configure TestNG to use shared system properties ? can't find any info about this.

Are you starting your webserver inside Selenium? This is one definitely one way of doing it :)

All selenium code is in a separate maven module, no dependencies either way. If system properties can't be shared I'll have to put the property in a separate file accessible by both modules.
